# What is the significance of non-commutative geometry in mathematics?

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, reference-request, big-picture

This is a question that has been winding around my head for a long time and I have not found a convincing answer. The title says everything, but I am going to enrich my question by little more explanations.

As a layman, I have started searching for expositories/more informal, rather intuitive, also original account of non-commutative geometry to get more sense of it, namely, I have looked through

- The English translation of [*Review of non-commutative geometry* by Alain Connes](http://www.ams.org/notices/199707/jones.pdf),
- [*Surveys in non-commutative geometry,* Clay mathematics proceedings, Volume 6](http://www.claymath.org/library/proceedings/cmip06.pdf),
- [*Non-commutative geometry* by Alain Connes](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf),

Nevertheless, I am not satisfied with them at all. It seems to me, that even understanding a simple example, requires much more knowledge that is gained in grad school. Now for me, this field merely contains a lot of highly developed machineries which are more technical (somehow artificial) than that of other fields.

The following are my questions revolving around the significance of this field in **Mathematics**. Of course, they are absolutely related to my main question.

> 1. How can a grad student be motivated to specialize in this field? and
> 2. What is (are) the well-known *result*(s), found solely by non-commutative geometric techniques that could not be proven without them?

Comment: I think Alain Valette's answer to your Q2 is a very good example. As for Q1, I have found that some combination of "there is some beautiful mathematics here" and "there might be a better chance of getting a grant or a postdoc if you do this, than if you do something idiotic like the cohomology of Banach algebras", quite forceful.

Comment: Fist of all, it's easy to understand simple example at grad level (at least a decent grad level) : it's $C*-algebra theory for example, or even easier, it's algebraic geometry. Both are foundations and motivate NCG.
Second, as for the contribution to existing maths of purely NCG theory, I'm not a specialist at all, but if I remember well what Connes said at a talk (but I didn't get much of it honestly), one achievement would be to prove Riemann's hypothesis in terms of the NCG analog model of the Weil proof of Riemann's hypothesis.

Comment: Personally, I have come to believe more in good mathematics than in important mathematics, but one could perhaps attribute that to sour grapes...

Comment: @Amin: I know people in operator algebras who most definitely do not see themselves as doing NC(D)G or NCT. There seems to be a lot more to NCG than C*-algebras, and more to C*-algebras than NCG

Comment: @Amin: what do you mean by "it's algebraic geometry"? also, I don't take $C*-algebra as a real example of NCG!

Comment: @ehsanmo: if you look up my own work to date and background, you will see that I might possibly have been very slightly sarcastic. If you want to believe NCG is "idiotic", go for it. Like I said, learn to do good mathematics, before worrying about "important" mathematics

Comment: @ehsanmo: I agree with Yemon, you have better chances to get a grant or a job if you can say you are in NCG... Remember that, besides "good" or "important" mathematics, there are also "sexy" and "fashionable" mathematics...

Comment: @Yemon Choi and @ehsanmo: You're totally right about NCG, C*-algebras and algebraic geometry being distinct with no inclusion of one in other, I was just meaning to point on common $roots$ between all of them, the latter two being, imo, the only accessible at grad level.  

Comment: @Alain Valette: How would you rank NCG in the category of top 5 important and fashionable subjects? I know, it's a naive question, though.

Comment: While the original question was quite good, I have to say that these comments are descending very rapidly into "subjective and argumentative" territory.   MO is absolutely not about "ranking" subjects etc.  Also, shouldn't this be community wiki... 

Comment: @Mattew Daws: I agree, but by that I wanted to find out more about interests in this field, since not only there is no one in my math department who's working on a related subject, but when I look into faculty members' specializations of leading and well-known math dep. throughout the word, I hardly find anyone currently working in this field, also. So the Alain Valette's comment's motivated me to ask such a marketing question. 

Comment: ehsanmo, it is counterproductive to think like this, and I suspect your list of "leading and well-known math dep" is more subjective than you realize. Trying to put a total order on domains of maths is specious. I see from your profile that you are still at an early stage of your studies/career, so I reiterate that you should concentrate on finding mathematics that appeals to you and where good work is being done. My opening remarks about grant success were really meant ironically, and in any case only really apply later in your mathematical development.

Comment: Dear @Yemon Choi: In fact, I don't intend to think like that. I wanted to know what the reactions are when I say the words that I was told some years ago about this field. This might be another subject for discussion. BTW, I've intended to work in a field which has common features of NCG, in some sense, regarding the grant, postdoc, etc. and now, is not very supported and funded, but it appeals me the most, is still growing and good works are being done.         

Comment: www2.cnrs.fr/sites/communique/.../la_geometrie_non_commutative.pdf

Comment: The preceding reference explains what really non-commutative geometry is (in mathematics, and , above all, in physics !) It was published when Connes got gold medal from CNRS (2004).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\coker{coker}$I think I'm in a pretty good position to answer this question because I am a graduate student working in noncommutative geometry who entered the subject a little bit skeptical about its relevance to the rest of mathematics.  To this day I sometimes find it hard to get excited about purely "noncommutative" results, but the subject has its tentacles in so many other areas that I never get bored.

Before saying anything further, I need to say a few words about the Atiyah–Singer index theorem.  This theorem asserts that if $D$ is an elliptic differential operator on a manifold $M$ then its Fredholm index $\dim(\ker(D)) - \dim(\coker(D))$ can be computed by integrating certain characteristic classes of $M$.  Non-trivial corollaries (obtained by "plugging in" well chosen differential operators) include the generalized Gauss–Bonnet formula, the Hirzebruch signature theorem, and the Hirzebruch–Riemann–Roch formula.  It was quickly realized (first by Atiyah, I think) that the proof of the theorem can be viewed as a statement about the Poincaré duality pairing between topological K-theory and its associated homology theory (these days called K-homology).

I wasn't around, but I'm told that people were very excited about Atiyah and Singer's achievement (understandably so!).  People quickly began trying to generalize and strengthen the theorem, and my claim is that noncommutative geometry is the area of mathematics that emerged from these attempts.  Saying that marginalizes the other important reasons for developing the subject, but I think it was Connes' main motivation and in any event it is a convenient oversimplification for a MO answer.  It also helps me answer your first question by playing to my personal biases: when I was choosing an area of research I told my adviser that I was interested in learning more about that Atiyah–Singer index theorem and I was led inexorably toward the tools of noncommutative geometry.

The origin of the relationship between NCG and Atiyah–Singer lies in equivariant index theory.  Atiyah and Singer realized from the start that if $M$ admits an action by a compact Lie group $G$ and $D$ is invariant under the group action then it is better to think of the index of $D$ as a virtual representation of $G$ (i.e. an element of the $G$-equivariant K-theory of a point) rather than as an integer.  If $G$ is not compact then this doesn't really work, but the noncommutative geometers realized that $D$ does have an index in the K-theory of the *reduced group C$^\ast$-algebra* $C_r^\ast(G)$.  Indeed, to a noncommutative geometer equivariant index theory is all about a map $K_\ast(M) \to K_\ast(C_r^\ast(M)$ where $K_\ast(M)$ is the K-homology of $M$; in the case where $M$ is the universal classifying space of $G$, Baum and Connes conjectured that this map is an isomorphism.  Proving this conjecture for more and more groups and understanding its consequences motivates a great deal of the development of NCG to this day.

The conjecture is interesting in its own right if you already care about index theory, but even if you don't injectivity of the Baum–Connes map implies the Novikov conjecture (see Alain Valette's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/88187)) and surjectivity is related to the Borel conjecture.  It has numerous other applications, for example to the theory of positive scalar curvature obstructions in Riemannian geometry or to the Kadison–Kaplansky conjecture in functional analysis (which would follow from surjectivity).  Recently there has been a lot of interest in connections between the Baum–Connes conjecture and representation theory; the Baum–Aubert–Plyman conjecture in $p$-adic representation theory has its origins in these sorts of considerations.

Much of the rest of NCG can also be traced back to index theory.  Kasparov's KK-theory arose as a way to understand maps and pairings between K-theory and K-homology, motivated in part by index theory.  Connes' work on noncommutative measure theory arose from his work on index theory for measurable foliations (with applications to dynamical systems).  Cyclic (co)homology was invented in part to gain access in a noncommutative setting to the Chern character map from K-theory to cohomology which translates the K-theoretic formulation of the index theorem into a cohomological formula.  Connes' theory of spectral triples and noncommutative Riemannian geometry is based on the theory of Dirac operators which was invented by Atiyah and Singer to prove the index theorem.  I guess my point with all of this is that all the esoteric machinery of NCG seems less artificial when viewed through the lens of index theory.

Comment: 
Just to add up something to this nice answer I'd like to mention that (exactly through NC index theorems) NCgeometry contributed much in understanding foliations. Much work is by now devoted to the non commutative geometry of foliations. The idea is that this direction will lead to a better understanding also of singular foliations.

Comment: Excellent answer - as soon as I saw original question, was hoping you would show up with an answer.

Comment: Just an ignoramus's question: does noncommutative algebra come in the picture when doing NCG? Is the field called "NC-Algebraic Geometry" flourishing?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Thanks for the encouraging words!  I can't resist this sort of question...

Comment: @Suvrit: I should have made a disclaimer at the outset of my answer that I am only informed about the analytic and topological aspects of NCG (a la Connes) and not NCAG.  My understanding is that NCAG developed largely separately and for different reasons, though I think there are some like Jonathan Block and Ryszard Nest who straddle the line.  That said, both areas use a lot of noncommutative algebra; in Connes' approach it enters via Hochschild and cyclic (co)homology.

Comment: *"Before saying anything further, I need to say a few words about the Atiyah-Singer index theorem."*  Paul, if I had a dollar for every time I've heard you preface something with that sentence, I'd be a very rich man.

Comment: You're just jealous because you haven't thought of a better pick-up line. :)

Comment: Just seen this conversation. Well, Paul, I think we know how you started or will start your marriage proposal...

Answer (score 30):

My favorite example concerns the Novikov conjecture, on the homotopy invariance of higher signatures for closed manifolds with fundamental group $G$: see
[Novikov conjecture on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_conjecture)
(note that this Wikipedia entry rather stupidly says that it has been proved for finitely generated abelian groups: that's correct, but it was proved for MANY more groups, e.g. hyperbolic groups, countable subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, etc.…). I think we agree that this is a conjecture in topology.

Now, look at this remarkable result by Guoliang Yu, from [The coarse Baum–Connes conjecture for spaces which admit a uniform embedding into Hilbert space](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002229900032):

"If the group $G$ admits a coarse embedding into Hilbert space, then it satisfies the Novikov conjecture."

A coarse embedding is a map $f:G\rightarrow L^2$ for which there exist control functions $\rho_{\pm}:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\rho_\pm(t)=\infty$, which “control” $f$ in the sense that, for every $x,y\in G$:

$$\rho_-(\lvert x^{-1}y\rvert_S)\leq\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert_2\leq \rho_+(\lvert x^{-1}y\rvert_S),$$
where $\lvert{.}\rvert_S$ denotes word length with respect to some finite generating subset $S$ in $G$. The existence of a coarse embedding is a weak metric condition (actually we know of basically just one class of groups which do not admit such an embedding, the “Gromov monsters”). And this weak metric condition, quite surprisingly, implies a strong consequence in topology.

Now my point is that the two known proofs of Yu's result (the original one, and the one by Skandalis–Tu–Yu, see [The coarse Baum–Connes conjecture and groupoids](https://web.archive.org/web/20180413034320/www.math.univ-metz.fr/%7Etu/publi/coarse.pdf)) both appeal in a fundamental way to the tools of non-commutative geometry: $C^*$-algebras, $K$-theory, groupoids, Kasparov's $KK$-theory (to be precise: “equivariant $KK$-theory for groupoids”).

Now to answer your first question: how to motivate a graduate student? Well, the subject mixes classical geometry, algebraic topology, non-commutative algebra, functional analysis, so it is one of those subjects that give you a feeling of the unity of mathematics….

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that !

Comment: Just as an addendum, and with caveat that AV can explain this better than I can. There's an article by Connes, late 80s or early 90s, where he mentions some of the work on the Novikov conjecture done using the early incarnations of the machinery mentioned. Unfortunately my copy is buried somewhere in my office, but I vaguely recall it used index theory for $C(T^n)=C*(Z^n)$ to give a proof of Novikov's conjecture for abelian groups, as motivation for the need to do differentiyal geometry on noncommutative spaces, viz. K-theory of C*-algebras, cyclic cohomology & Chern character, etc

Comment: I'd also put in a word for the Kadison-Kaplansky conjecture: in this case the problem originates in analysis rather than topology, but it seems that some of the most significant progress has either used NCG or used tools which received a lot of impetus from work in NCG

Comment: @Yemon: Why don't you expand your relevant comment on Kaplansky-Kadison into a separate answer? 

Comment: Alain, it has been a long time since I read about these things properly, and I am out of the office so cannot use MathSciNet to patch the gaps in my memory. Perhaps I will try to write something when I get back to the office.

Comment: "note that this Wikipedia entry rather stupidly says..." Why not edit it then?

Comment: @Dear Alain: many thanks for your explanations. One of the reasons that I chose the Paul's answer is the sense that I got from the way he tried to relate important (classical) results that I've at least heard of many times to the known facts developed by NCG's method. As for my Q1, I'd say, unity of math sounds heroic and I don't really consider it as a motivation.    

Comment: Your link to the result of Guoliang Yu seems beyond the reach even of the Wayback Machine, so I used MathSciNet to search out the name of a likely paper.  I hope that I got it correct.

Comment: Dear @DavidCorfield, I am grateful to Mr Valette for leaving an answer here and regarding wikipedia i have the following comments to make: 1 In some languages like french the moderators/main editors of wiki are little tyrants and make it very unpleasant to try to contribute. So someone may have been deterred by that. 2 Some people just don't even know that wikipedia can be edited by anyone. 3 Some may feel uncomfortable with editing other ppl's work. After all it is quite unnatural in most situations in life: when you disagree with someone the reflex is to criticize, not change what he says.

Answer (score 13):

There are much better answers above than this one, but:

If you believe fiber bundles are important to classical mathematics, then you probably believe fibrations are, and maybe foliations are, as well. If you don't, note that a foliation of a smooth manifold is a decomposition of the manifold into integral submanifolds (roughly, solutions to differential equations). You can't get much more classical than this. In his book *Noncommutative Geometry* Connes tried to make it clear that to understand the leaf space of a foliation, more is needed than the classical quotient construction, groupoids and noncommutative geometry give more information about a patently classical "space". You probably say: So what?  There are other ways. Connes tries then to show us that there is a connection between a fundamental von Neumann algebra invariant (the flow of weights) and one of the key invariants for a codimension 1 foliation (the Godbillon-Vey class), which appears in the first chapter on many introductory accounts of foliations. I find it hard to believe that this is coincidental. For me, this warrants closer investigation.

The index theorem for measured foliations discussed above perhaps grew from a seed like the above mentioned connection. (I wonder what we need to do to get Connes to weigh-in over here at MO?)

Comment: And Kasparov, Moscovici, Baum, ...

Comment: Thanks, Yemon. I was thinking of Connes's book, and neglected to type that.

Comment: We should at least be thankful that we have Alain Valette!

Comment: I second that, Paul!

Answer (score 9):

Alain's [answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20201215161659/https://alainconnes.org/docs/ckm1.pdf) is the best application I heard about.
I cannot add something comparable. Just two "motivations" which are
somewhat nice to me. However they does not answer yours questions, sorry.

**General claim** -  studying non-commutative objects is useful for understanding commutative ones.

**Subclaim** - non-commutative algebras can be equivalent (Morita, Koszul dual or whatever)   to non-commutative ones, however non-commutative "models" can provide an easier way to study commutative things.

**Examples 1.** Consider the commutative algebra $A$ of functions on a manifold $M$ and a group $G$ acting on $M$. You may be interested in factor $M/G$ which is related to invariants $A^G$.

**Claim.** Under certain conditions COMMUTATIVE $A^G$ is Morita equivalent to NON-COMMUTATIVE
$A\ltimes C[G]$ - the crossed-product algebra of $A$ and group algebra of $G$.
In some cases it is easier to work with this crossed-product sometimes it can be
described more explicitly.
You may see just the first sentences in Etingof–Ginzburg's famous paper:
[Symplectic reflection algebras, Calogero-Moser space, and deformed Harish-Chandra homomorphism](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011114).

**Example 2. Quantization**. Our real world is actually quantum. So physicists
are interested in this. A mathematical way to understand quantization
is a procedure to construct the non-commutative algebras from commutative ones.
The big mathematical challenge is to understand how to relate
properties on non-commutative quantum algebras to properties of commutative ones.
Probably the most striking and most simple formulated is the conjecture
that automorphisms group of classical symplectic  $\mathbb R^{2n}$  and quantum (i.e. just the algebra of differential operators in $n$-variables) are isomorphic.
[Automorphisms of the Weyl algebra by
Alexei Belov-Kanel, Maxim Kontsevich](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512169).

It is somewhat related to the famous Jacobian conjecture.
See [Belov-Kanel and Kontsevich - The Jacobian Conjecture is stably equivalent to the Dixmier Conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512171).

Comment: Although presently correct as well, I think the subclaim has one 'non-' too many :)

Answer (score 5):

The spectral characterization of Riemannian manifolds is a good example in my opinion. Details are given in [Connes - A unitary invariant in Riemannian geometry](https://web.archive.org/web/20201215161659/https://alainconnes.org/docs/ckm1.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Connes has on his home page a very nice downloadable survey article "A view of mathematics" which also gives a good idea of the role of groupoids in this area, and links with many topics mentioned by others above.

I have also raised the question of the problem of applying these or related techniques to algebraically structured groupoids:

[Convolution algebras for double groupoids?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86617/convolution-algebras-for-double-groupoids)

Since "motivating graduate students" was part of the original question, someone needs to point out at least one thing that has not been done.  It can be useful to explain the "exterior" of a subject: unknowns, known unknowns, etc! One would also like the experts to point out anomalies in this area: I won't try to define this term, but they can lie around unrecognised.

Answer (score 3):

There is interplay among the three topics of "[Hopf Algebras, Renormalization and Noncommutative Geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9808042)" by Connes and Kreimer (1998), which are of continuing interest as illustrated by Kreimer and Yeats' "[Diffeomorphisms of quantum fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01837)" (2017), Yeats' "[A Combinatorial Perspective on Quantum Field Theory](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ekayeats/teaching/co739/A%2BCombinatorial%2BPerspective%2Bon%2BQuantum%2BF.pdf)" (2017), and Balduf's "[Perturbation theory of transformed quantum fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.00686)" (2019). (Trees and vector fields play integral roles.)

Edit Dec. 18, 2021:

Interesting applications of NC geometry to investigations of Monstrous Moonshine can be found via the workshop synopsis "[Novel approaches to the finite simple groups](https://www.birs.ca/workshops/2012/12frg158/report12frg158.pdf)" by John McKay and Roland Friedrich (2012):

> As an effect of the early preparation of all attendees, several conjectures previously made, in particular by J. McKay, could in fact be turned into concrete research plans during the time in Banff, one example being the application of non-commutative geometry and the Bost-Connes system to Monstrous Moonshine and replicability.

(Anyone have a copy or link to Jorge Plazas' roadmap mentioned in the synopsis?)

There are connections among noncommutative free probability theory, enumerative combinatorics (e.g. noncrossing partitions), random matrix models, NC geometry, and Monstrous Moonshine as well. See, e.g., the He and Jejalla ref in OEIS [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264).

Comment: See also the intro to the survey  "Lessons from Quantum Field Theory: Hopf Algebras and Spacetime Geometries"
by Connes and Kreimer (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9904044). Vector fields and the Witt algebra related to the generators $-x^{n+1}d/dx$ are central. Also see "Cyclic cohomology and Hopf algebras" by
Connes and Moscovici (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9904154)

Comment: See intro to "Exponential Formulas, Normal Ordering and the Weyl-Heisenberg Algebra" by Stjepan Meljanac and Rina Štrajn https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.12593

Answer (score -2):

In Veltman's *Diagrammatica*, the full Lagrangian of the standard model is spelt out. This has around a hundred terms. This is way too many for even the most dedicated physicist (or physically inclined mathematician) to work on, except by piece by piece.

In the Connes-Lott-Barrett-Chamseddine model, based on non-commutative geometry, the standard model is derived from a spectral action with a simple geometric input, spacetime is multiplied with a 'fat' non-commutative point:

> $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{H}_L \oplus \mathbb{H}_R \oplus M_3(\mathbb{C})$

It is zero-dimensional, classically but has KO-theory dimension 6. This reproduces the full standard model including the Higgs and neutrino mixing. It turns out that the bimodule over the dual of this fat point, which is the sum of all irreducible irreps of odd dimension gives one full generation of the fermions. It's worth noting that the spectral action is a generalisation of the Einstein-Hilbert action.

The theory is not limited to just the standard model. In a later paper with Chamseddine, Connes shows how NCG can model a grand unification theory like the Pati-Salam SU(5) GUT.

Although non-commutative geometry is a geometry without a geometry. I mean by this that they work with a non-commutative algebra to be thought of as the algebra of functions on a non-commutative geometry which has not  bern constructed yet.  I'm not so sure that this will be the case in the near future (or perhaps the far near future given the density of maths required to understand and work with NCG). One of the standard examples of a non-commutative space, according to Connes,  is the irrational torus where classical tools do not give any information but non-commutative tools can. However, diffeology, which is a generalisation of classical differential geometry, does and it gives roughly similar results to that of Connes.

I'd also add that Mathilde Marcolli has elaborated an explanation of the fractional quantum Hall effect and which has taken its point of departure from Bellisard, van Elst & Schulz-Baldes *The Non-Commutative Geometry of the Quantum Hall Effect* (1994) and which she calls the earliest work on physics in NCG. They show that the magnetic field turns the Brillioun zone into a non-commutative torus.

She has also published a recent book with Connes, titled *Non-commutative Geometry, Quantum Fields and Motives*. Here as a reviewer at the AMS says in 2007:

> So the cat is out of the bag. What greater mathematical objective can there be to realise the RH [Riemann Hypothesis] for number fields and the RH for function fields as two sides of the same coin, the discriminators being as it were, algebraic geometry and (or versus) non-commutative geometry? This is manifestly one aspect of the rationale for what the entire sweeping programme is about, with a complementary aspect of quantum physics in its post-Feynman form.

> What a wild, wild ride!

An understatement.

I imagine the latter is the reason behind another book that Marcolli has published, this time simply titled *Feynman Motives*.

Answer (score -4):

Although there are more than one great answers to this question here but I am surprised no one has pointed out the greatest theme (my opinion) of Professor Connes' work. He has reproduced the Standard Model of physics from purely mathematical work which is worthy of history books. He has given a fundamentally different direction to our quest for understanding the world. Essentially, (as per my understanding), he extends the geometrical picture of gravity given by Einstein to explain all of physics as geometry. Not only that, his geometrical world also has in-built time evolution. He explains all this as starting from Heisenberg's matrix picture. Although many say Heisenberg's and Schrodinger's pictures are the same, he introduces the basic notion of non-commutativity with this matrix mechanics and uncertainty principle. He gives a whole new calculus to perform differentiation and integration etc. I don't know why his work is not talked about more.

(I would love if someone could point out if I am wrong partially or completely because I am neither a mathematician nor a physicist.)

Comment: "He has reproduced the Standard Model of physics from purely mathematical work which is worthy of history books." Even if one believes one can get physics purely from mathematics, the breathless tone of this praise gives the impression that no one else has worked on the mathematics of the Standard Model

Comment: "Although many say Heisenberg's and Schrodinger's pictures are the same, he introduces the basic notion of non-commutativity with this matrix mechanics and uncertainty principle" -- once again, QM existed before Connes.

Comment: Wonderful as Connes's NCG book is, I don't think it ever claimed to supersede or render obsolete all the work done before it

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Given that the poster has said that he isn't a professional mathematician or physicist, I don't quite see the point of your criticisms. That as a non-mathematician and physicist he has heard of NCG to me is already a thing of wonder.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: And nor is his tone vastly different to much of popular writing on QM which even after a century has passed is still trying to astonish us with just how bizarre, anti-intuitive and strange the quantum world is.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: He also says, "he explains all this *starting* from Heisenberg's matrix mechanics". So the poster is acknowledging prior work on non-commutativity (or at least matrix mechanics - the poster might not appreciate that matices are inherently non-commutative) and also prior work on QM. I think he understands that QM was already around before Connes got to work on it. And his breathless tone only betrays excitement.

Comment: @MoziburUllah MO, and dare I say i mathematics, is not about generating breathless excitement but about increasing understanding. MO is a site for those of us in the business of mathematical research; and my local pub is a site (COVID permitting) for breathless discussion with my friends.

Comment: The original post asked particular questions, presumably hoping for **informed** answers. MO is not a general discussion board, and I don't think this particular answer adds anything, especially given the other detailed older answers

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Like I already said, the post was by someone who admitted quite freely that he was not a professional mathematician or physicist. I daresay he was excited because he had understood something which hadn't before - whichbis that the standard model can be written in an elegant manner unlike the warts and all description in Veltman's *Diagramaticca* which had over a hundred terms and which Connes said took him around four hours to typeset properly.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: You can also see that in my post I quote an AMS reviewer who looking at Connes programme, calls it a "what a wild, wild ride!" Now that's what I call breathless excitement and from a professional research mathematician who isn't afraid to express his emotions in a publically available journal and not just down in the pub with his mates. So if him, then why not the poster?