# Benefits for Riemannian geometry from noncommutative analysis?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, noncommutative-geometry

Possible duplicate: [What is the significance of non-commutative geometry in mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88184/what-is-the-significance-of-non-commutative-geometry-in-mathematics)

Hi,
I've read some introductory articles and lecture notes on (Connes) noncommutative geometry that generalizes Riemannian geometry.  I was wondering whether there are any benifits/results in the back direction, i.e. Results in Riemannian geometry that are obtained by methods in noncommutative geometry?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88184/what-is-the-significance-of-non-commutative-geometry-in-mathematics for some examples.  There are lots of applications to foliations and index theory, to name just two examples.  Also, in a slightly different vein, the rational injectivity of the assembly map (keyword: Baum-Connes conjecture) implies the Novikov conjecture.

Comment: In fact, I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of the one I linked to.